# Android Xml File: full phone screen width (to display caller name)

Tags: android, xml, width, android-fullscreen

I just built an app similar to TrueCaller but I have an issue with displaying the caller name. I tried `match_parent` & `fill_parent` & `wrap_content` methods in XML, but I'm having issues.

I want to set the width to the phone screen width.

How can I achieve this? Here is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_arsenic"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_arsenic"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="#789546"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/active"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activaa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="monospace" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- android:onClick="onPurchaseClick" -->

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated, better not to use it. 
I tried to fix your layout by simply keeping only one parent layout.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#789546"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/active"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activaa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace"/>

    <!-- android:onClick="onPurchaseClick" -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This Code is Not Work Properly.this code to not set width to phone screen size

Comment: See my updated answer. I changed wrap_content to match_parent in root layout.

Comment: I updated your code but again this code is not work properly .i want to set width to phone screen width.